# React native getall AsyncStorage and create array

Tags: react-native

get all data and create the array after the send get site
how can I do it

[[image: 1]]

Comment: How you want to final array.  Like this [ { key1:value1 }, { key2:value2 } ]  ?

Comment: { key2:value2 } this is convenient

Answer (score 0):

```
async getAllData(){
  try {
    const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
    return stores.map((store) => { return {[store[0]]: store[1]} })

  }catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
    return []
  }  
}
```

**Invoking the method**

```
getAllData().then((response)=> {
  if(response.length){
    console.log(response)
    //Here you can call your API
   }else{
     console.log("NO RECORD FOUND")
   }
})
```

Comment: If the answer has fulfilled your requirement. Please close the answer. Or If you have any issue with answer feel free to ask.